# What is an efficient way to make an image button of my preferred size in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

So I'm brand new to Android Studio, and I'm trying to make a personal planner app.  I want to make image buttons into tiles like this to access different activities.

Here is a screenshot of my app so far

[image]

I made the images on MS Powerpoint and copied them into paint and kept resizing them and copying them into Android Studio until I found a size that fits the screen well.  Also in doing this, the images have become distorted (another reason why my method sucks).  I initially tried just resizing them in Android Studio but that makes them look 
like this (the image stays the same size but the grey area around it gets larger)

[image]

What is a good way to make these images into an appropriate size for an Image Button without distorting them?

Answer (score 1):

There are different dimensions for different screen size and and densities.
Please learn [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) for more. And for fitting the layout with the screen try using LinearLayout with weightSum and weight OR GridLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Set layout_height and layout_width to wrap_content and put images in drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-mdpi with proper dimention.